# Exec format error: ./idea.sh after linux crash during intellij update

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, zsh

Intellij was updating and it stated the update was finished, prompting me to choose wether to get config from past installation or somewhere else. As I was about to click ok for the previous installation option, my whole system froze(kubuntu).The song I was listening to kept repeating the same second of music through the headphones. Maybe it was an overheat issue on my laptop? Anyway, had to hard reset it.

Now I can't open intellij. The icon is blank, clicking on it shows loading for a while, but then never does anything. Running the idea.sh from terminal produces the aforementioned error.

What's the best course of action here, to save all my configurations and settings before reinstalling? Or is there a way to fix this without reinstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a clean installation from from the `.tar.gz` file available at the [official downloads page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).

Make sure to unpack into the empty directory (not on top of the previous version).

Check if you have the [config folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) for the new version already created. If it's present, remove it. This will make IntelliJ IDEA prompt you to import the settings from the previous version (make sure not to delete the config folder from the previous version you will be importing from).

Comment: Thank you! It didn't want to import settings at first. Then I relocated the previous version folder and it did, but I suspect that had nothing to do with it. I pasted it back before pointing to it as the previous version config folder. Now I have two folders for the two versions. Will the new folder be the one used from now on? Will it be the one I will want to back up in the future for similar cases? Can I safely delete the old version folder?

Comment: Yes, you can delete the old config folders.